# Undefined Offset PHP error, arrays are defined

Tags: php

Getting an Undefined Offset error here -- apparently from the $newval array.

Note that the {exp} tag is not PHP, and is simply a sql query by my CMS system which creates the $bags array for me.

```
<?php

$bags = array();
$newval = array();
$pattern = "[^0-9]";

{exp:query sql="SELECT m_field_id_1 as bags FROM exp_member_data WHERE m_field_id_1 IS NOT NULL"}
$bags[] = "{bags}";
{/exp:query}

foreach ($bags as $key => $value) {
for ( $i = 0, $s = strlen($value); $i < $s; $i++) {
    if ( is_numeric($value[$i]) ) {
        $newval[$key] .= $value[$i];
    }
}
}

$sum = array_sum($newval);
$format = number_format($sum);

echo $format;

?>
```

Comment: Which line are you getting the error in exactly?

Comment: Remember you are starting from 0.  So you need to substract 1 from $s.

For example your string is 10 characters long that would be indexes 0-9 but not 10.

Comment: Wild guess: $value[$i] is probably at some point not defined. offset is concerned if the array key exists - not if the array is defined at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can concatenate to a variable, that variable must exist (to avoid a `Notice`). Simply declare `$newval[$key]` as an empty string before the `for` loop:

```
foreach ($bags as $key => $value) {
    $newval[$key] = '';
    for ($i = 0, $s = strlen($value); $i < $s; $i++) {
        if ( is_numeric($value[$i]) ) {
            $newval[$key] .= $value[$i];
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, there's nothing wrong with your starting value of `$i`. It is correct to have it at `0` and not `1` as others are suggesting.

However, if you're trying to remove non-number characters from a string and avoid empty array elements (as your original code does), you can remove the inner `for` loop and simply:

```
foreach ($bags as $key => $value) {
    $digits = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $value);
    if (strlen($digits)) {
        $newval[$key] = $digits;
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely, stereofrog. I just felt I was doing a little too much refactoring at that point :)

Comment: Defining $newval[$key] did the trick -- The reason I used a loop instead of preg_replace was that I've read it parses quicker. Truth to this?

Answer (score 1):

As Jrod said you're walking through the characters in `$value` but you start at 0. `strlen()` returns the absolute amount of chars in $value so in your for loop you should start at 1 instead of 0.

This is the code you should use:

```
<?php

$bags = array();
$newval = array();
$pattern = "[^0-9]";

{exp:query sql="SELECT m_field_id_1 as bags FROM exp_member_data WHERE m_field_id_1 IS NOT NULL"}
$bags[] = "{bags}";
{/exp:query}

foreach ($bags as $key => $value) {
    $newval[$key] = '';
for ( $i = 1, $s = strlen($value); $i < $s; $i++) {
    if ( is_numeric($value[$i]) ) {
        $newval[$key] .= $value[$i];
    }
}
}

$sum = array_sum($newval);
$format = number_format($sum);

echo $format;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
foreach ($bags as $key => $value) {
for ( $i = 0, $s = strlen($value); $i < $s; $i++) {
    if ( is_numeric($value[$i]) ) {
        $newval[$key] .= $value[$i];
    }
}
}
```

you can write

```
 $newval = preg_replace('~\D+~', '', $bags);
```

one line is easier to debug than six, isn't it.